# SQL - group by и order by. По какому принципу идет сортировка?

Tags: sql, postgresql

По какому принципу идет сортировка одинаковых значений?

```
SELECT  billing_country,
SUM(total),
COUNT(total),
AVG(total)
FROM invoice
WHERE  billing_country = 'USA'
GROUP BY billing_city
ORDER BY AVG(total);
```

Comment: Сортировать и группировать можно, но не агрегированную функцию в одном запросе.
создайте подзапрос и на псевдоним пишите сортировку либо на поле без агрегации

Comment: *По какому принципу идет сортировка одинаковых значений?* Если значение выражения сортировки совпадает, то порядок таких записей в выходном наборе не определён. То есть порядок записей в группе формально случаен, и в следующий раз при выполнении этого же запроса может быть иным.

Comment: Записи внутри группы записей с одинаковым значением полей сортировки идут в произвольном порядке, о конкретике этого порядка можно только гадать. Причём, этот принцип независим от того, есть у вас `group by` или нет, просто каждая группа, образовавшаяся с помощью `group by` рассматривается в данном аспекте как отдельный запрос и сортировка идёт внутри каждой группы отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

Выдержка из [справки](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/queries-order):

> После того как запрос выдал таблицу результатов (после обработки
> списка выборки), её можно отсортировать. Если сортировка не задана,
> строки возвращаются в неопределённом порядке. Фактический порядок
> строк в этом случае будет зависеть от плана соединения и сканирования,
> а также от порядка данных на диске, поэтому полагаться на него нельзя.
> Определённый порядок выводимых строк гарантируется, только если этап
> сортировки задан явно.

Таким образом, если критерий сортировки не задает порядок явным образом он остается неопределенным, как вам писали выше.